# cannot load selected image into UI

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

```
class RoundedImageFile extends StatelessWidget {
  final PlatformFile image;
  final double size;

  const RoundedImageFile({
    required Key key,
    required this.image,
    required this.size,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: size,
      width: size,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
          image: AssetImage(image.path!),
        ),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(size)),
        color: Colors.black,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I want to load the selected image in the interface.
I'm using the file picker, I have a doubt about AssetImage();

[error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvR9k.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use Image.file which will load image from file.

```
Image.file(File(
 //picked.path
);
```